# My step counter in java doesnt count steps when app is running in background or closed

Tags: java, android

I got this code, which is a tutorial improved with a feature that reset steps days after days.

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private TextView stepCountTextView;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor stepSensor;
    private int stepCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        stepCountTextView = findViewById(R.id.stepCountTextView);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (sensorManager != null) {
            stepSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
            if (stepSensor == null) {
                stepCountTextView.setText("Step Counter sensor not available!");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (stepSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
        int todaystepcount = SharedPreferencesManager.getInt(this, "todaystepcount", 0);
        Log.d("feor", "d");
        stepCountTextView.setText("Steps: " + todaystepcount);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (stepSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {

            stepCount = (int) event.values[0];
            String storedDate = SharedPreferencesManager.getString(this, "date", "");
            boolean isSameDate = DateUtils.isSameDateAsStored(storedDate);
            if (isSameDate) {
                Log.d("feor", "a");
                int totalstepcount = SharedPreferencesManager.getInt(this, "totalstepcount", 0);
                Log.d("feor", "b");
                SharedPreferencesManager.saveInt(this, "todaystepcount", stepCount-totalstepcount);
                Log.d("feor", "c");


            } else {
                Log.d("feor", "e");
                int totalstepcount = SharedPreferencesManager.getInt(this, "totalstepcount", 0);
                Log.d("feor", "f");
                int todaystepcount = SharedPreferencesManager.getInt(this, "todaystepcount", 0);
                Log.d("feor", "g");
                SharedPreferencesManager.saveInt(this, "totalstepcount", todaystepcount+totalstepcount);
                Log.d("feor", "h");
                SharedPreferencesManager.saveInt(this, "yesterdaystepcount", todaystepcount);
                Log.d("feor", "i");
                SharedPreferencesManager.saveInt(this, "todaystepcount", 0);
                Log.d("feor", "j");
                SharedPreferencesManager.saveString(this, "date", DateUtils.getCurrentDate());
                Log.d("feor", "k");
                stepCountTextView.setText("Steps: " + SharedPreferencesManager.getInt(this, "todaystepcount", 0));
            }




        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Not used in this example
    }
}


 class DateUtils {

    public static boolean isSameDateAsStored(String storedDate) {
        String currentDate = getCurrentDate();
        return currentDate.equals(storedDate);
    }

    public static String getCurrentDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        return dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
}



 class SharedPreferencesManager {

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefs";

    public static void saveInt(Context context, String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static int getInt(Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }

 }
```

How can I make the app count steps in the background too?
Is this regulated in the code or in the manifest for example?
And are there other problems?

Thanks you so much

I tried differents tutorials in java and search online but found nothing.